# C naked function - searing solution to execute both assembly and c code in 1 function

Tags: c, freertos

id like to trace freertos isr's.
freertos uses for 2 isr (irq handler) naked functions.

id like to make at entrylevel and exit level a trace call as follows (uncommented)

```
#warning "system no longer operating with trace call since naked,.. solve"
void vPortSVCHandler( void )
{
  //hal_trace_wrapper_isr_enter(SVCall_IRQn); // modified

    __asm volatile (
                    "   ldr r3, pxCurrentTCBConst2      \n" /* Restore the context. */
                    "   ldr r1, [r3]                    \n" /* Use pxCurrentTCBConst to get the pxCurrentTCB address. */
                    "   ldr r0, [r1]                    \n" /* The first item in pxCurrentTCB is the task top of stack. */
                    "   ldmia r0!, {r4-r11}             \n" /* Pop the registers that are not automatically saved on exception entry and the critical nesting count. */
                    "   msr psp, r0                     \n" /* Restore the task stack pointer. */
                    "   isb                             \n"
                    "   mov r0, #0                      \n"
                    "   msr basepri, r0                 \n"
                    "   orr r14, #0xd                   \n"
                    "   bx r14                          \n"
                    "                                   \n"
                    "   .align 4                        \n"
                    "pxCurrentTCBConst2: .word pxCurrentTCB             \n"
                );

  //hal_trace_wrapper_isr_exit(SVCall_IRQn); // modified
}
```

the quick-idea was to extract the naked part in a own function. but then the stack pointers will carry a offset and i suspect i break the system totally.

is there another solution to execute both c and asm in 1 function?

Comment: SVC handler is not a regular interrupt. What exactly do you want to trace about it? Time spent in OS calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function has no compiler generated code at all, only the assembly instructions you see execute.  So really this is not a C function, but an assembly function.  It is naked to ensure there is absolutely no code added before the assembly instructions execute as the [FreeRTOS kernel](https://www.freertos.org) must have complete control over how the stack and registers are used.  If you remove the naked attribute, even if you replace it with an interrupt attribute, the code will not execute at all - it will be certain to crash.

Comment: Thanks for this statement. I was just trying to trace everything. But i leave the svc and pendsv oit pf this image

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers support generating ISRs using [interrupt](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html) attribute. You can try using it instead of naked functions.

Comment: Hi r3mus. Do you have an example at hand? ;-) would help me a lot. Thank you. Yes its cortex m

Comment: @ambedded, sorry, I don't have any experience writing ISRs for ARM, only for x86.